# Wordpress pornhub videos embed using wp_embed_register_handler not working

Tags: wordpress, embed

I've been trying to embed videos from pornhub in my [website](https://popularporn.xyz) using wordpress's `wp_embed_register_handler()`. I followed this example from [wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_embed_register_handler/#user-contributed-notes) but it's not working.

```
wp_embed_register_handler(
    'pornhub',
    '#https://www\.pornhub\.com/view_video.php?viewkey=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$#i',
    'wpdocs_embed_handler_pornhub'
);
 
function wpdocs_embed_handler_pornhub( $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr ) {
 
    $embed = sprintf(
            '<iframe src="https://www.pornhub.com/embed/%1$s" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
            esc_attr($matches[1])
            );
 
    return $embed;
}
```

I'm on latest version 5.4.2. Has it stopped working or I'm not doing it correctly?